# TimePicker Component value not populating in view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, timepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Initially while selecting the time `onchange` working properly.

```
 this.state = {
   driverReportingTime: ''
 }

<TimePicker className="form-control" onChange={this.handleTime.bind(this)} value={this.state.driverReportingTime} hintText="Time" />

handleTime(event, time) {
  this.setState({ driverReportingTime: time })
}
```

[image]

In the View mode If I want to populate the saved Time response in Screenshot

[image]

```
<TimePicker className="form-control" disabled value={singlejoborder.driverReportingTime} hintText="Time" />
```

The time is not populating.
Please let me know what I am doing wrong.
[image]

Comment: Are you talking about setting a default time? And if so, that can be done using ```defaultTime: '11'```.

Comment: What do you mean by view mode? Also never bind function directly in render instead do it in constructor always

Comment: similar, but not default I am getting the time from response as shown in screenshot in 2018-09-12T15:18:05.262Z this format I am not able to populate the exact time which i have selected 
Using moment("2018-09-12T15:18:05.262Z").format('HH:mm a') I am getting Time properly but still I am not able to populate

Comment: @Think-Twice I have a value which to be populated in the picker but i cannot able to populate

Comment: Have you tried moment(singlejoborder.driverReportingTime).format('HH.mm') ?

Comment: Yes, Still not showing, I checked in console time coming 20.48 but not populating in UI

Comment: anyone please help me

Comment: Can anyone suggest the solution for this

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
const time = moment(singlejoborder.driverReportingTime, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z").format("HH:mm") ;
console.log(time); //prints 23:35

<TimePicker className="form-control" disabled value={time} hintText="Time" />
```

Comment: No bro, still not working its not populating. only i can able to see in console

Comment: Ok May I know what you get time in this function handleTime(event, time) {
    this.setState({ driverReportingTime: time })
} can you do console of time and let me know

Comment: handleTime console.log(time)
Wed Sep 12 2018 23:01:37 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Comment: please check and let me know bro if possible

Answer (score 0):

You should consider first argument as time

```
handleTime(time) {
   this.setState({ driverReportingTime: time })
}
```

Comment: my question is not on HandleTime method time is populating correct only .
In the edit mode from store i am getting time that time I am not able to populate

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Comment: @user9883888 show the code where you call setState when edit mode

Comment: I am not populating the value from state, I am getting the response form API, The value i am getting(driverreportingTime) shared in screenshot.



<TimePicker className="form-control" disabled value={singlejoborder.driverReportingTime} hintText="Time" />

Comment: You didn't understand my comment clearly, It should be like this eg. axios.get(url).then(result => this.setState({ driverReportingTime: moment(time) })) in componentDidMount